# Can I loop over an expression in webflow?

Tags: spring-webflow

I am new to spring web flow. I have an list and I want an expression to be evaluated as many time as the size of the list. Sample code is-

```
<evaluate expression="myController.save(itemController.selectedList)" result="flowScope.item"/>
```

Here selectedList is an list of items. I want it to be something like-

```
for(Item item: selectedList) {
    <evaluate expression="myController.save(item)" result="flowScope.item"/>
}
```

Here I want iterating through the list and evaluation the expression with each iteration. Is this possible to do so in xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't really make sense. 
what you should do is call a service method or create a method in your controller that does this, myController. saveItemList(List itemList) which call the saveItem method on each item of the list and maybe returns a list of items too. 
Then you can call it from the XML

Comment: Hi rptmat57, thank you for your reply. I guess in the question I was not very clear on what I want to do. A better description is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711101/not-able-to-create-multiple-instances-of-an-input-set-in-flowscope. I hope you can help.